# IoCreateDeviceSecure function denies the access from member in Administrators

Tags: c, windows, security, driver

everyone. I am adding the access control for a driver (WinPcap's NDIS 6 filter driver) running on Windows 7 and 8. We want to let only administrators (users in Administrators group) to use the driver. So I used the new **IoCreateDeviceSecure** function instead of original **IoCreateDevice** call.

My code is as belows:

```
UNICODE_STRING sddl = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)");
const GUID guidClassNPF = { 0x26e0d1e0L, 0x8189, 0x12e0, { 0x99, 0x14, 0x08, 0x00, 0x22, 0x30, 0x19, 0x04 } };
status = IoCreateDeviceSecure(adriverObjectP, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION), &deviceName, FILE_DEVICE_TRANSPORT,
FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &sddl, (LPCGUID) &guidClassNPF, &devObjP);
```

My SDDL string is **"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)"** which means "**allows the kernel, system, and *administrator* complete control over the device. No other users may access the device.**" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563667(v=vs.85).aspx. But **GA** in that SDDL string means "**The built-in *Administrators group* on the machine**" by reference to the same webpage. Hence I don't know if this is Microsoft's mistake, because there is still difference between **Administrator user** and the **Administrators group**.

My testbed is Windows 8.1 x64. I have created a user named **test**, added it to the **Administrators group**. I used the **runas** command to run a program that invokes the driver as the user **test** as below:

Fails:

```
runas /savecred /user:test "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe -v -A 192.168.0.1"
```

And the command fails to open the driver device, I tried the command as the built-in Administrator user, and the driver device open succeeds. As below:

Succeeds:

```
runas /savecred /user:administrator "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe -v -A 192.168.0.1"
```

This test confirms that **"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)"** only allows the access of the exact **Administrator user** instead of **Administrators group**.

I hope that anyone can point it out if this is a bug in Windows, and how to allow the **Administrators group** to use my driver? Thanks.

---

It seems to be the UAC problem.

Besides, for a general view, I think our application scenario doesn't actually make use of the "Administrator" privilege. We just want to open access to Administrators group as a standard group instead of asking for Administrators' privilege. I think there must be some more graceful ways to solve this UAC issue.

And, I thought "BA" in SDDL should mean all accounts in Administrators group, there is no much relationship with whether the account in Administrators group has the "full" access token. As the current situation (default policies), if "BA" only means the built-in Administrator account, we can just provide the SID of Administrator account, instead of using "BA". So the predefined “BA" string is useless.

Comment: The Administrator account is initially disabled because it's not subject to UAC restrictions. All other users in the Administrators group are logged on with two separate tokens and logon sessions. The returned token is restricted. You have to elevate or use a SYSTEM service to get the linked administrator token. runas.exe cannot elevate. The task scheduler can via "run with highest privileges" (e.g. `schtasks.exe /create /ru test /rl highest /sc [schedule frequency] /st [start time] /tn [task name] /tr [command line]`).

Comment: To summarize: `runas` doesn't give you elevated privileges, so any operation that requires membership of the Administrators group won't work.

Comment: I tried interactively logging on the **test** user, the same result with **runas**, the driver device still fails to be opened, even without **User Account Control** prompt. It seems that all other users in the Administrators just don't have elevated privileges, is there any way to solve my requirement? I just want to open device's access to them, instead of using the elevated privileges.

Comment: GA means "generic all" - it's the access right you're granting, not who you're granting it to.   BA means the Administrators group.

Comment: You have to log in interactively, then run `nmap.exe` elevated, i.e., using the "run as admin" option.  When you don't use "run as admin", the Administrators group token is disabled, so you can't gain access using it.  Alternatively, if you want non-elevated processes to be able to access the device, use BU (the Users group) instead of BA.  Just make sure you don't introduce an elevation of privilege vulnerability.

Comment: Note that this is the intended behaviour.  It's like having to use sudo in Linux; being in the Administrators group has no effect on what you can do until you explicitly tell Windows to use that membership, which you do by choosing "run as admin".

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake in writting, all "GA" should be "BA", Administrators group.

Comment: I tested it and It works if nmap runs using the **"run as admin"** option. But  it's slightly inconvenient that the user needs to choose this option before using my driver. Is there other workaround that can fulfill my requirement? Like our driver first checks the members of Administrators group, then add the members to SDDL string in **IoCreateDeviceSecure** call instead of using "BA"?

Comment: You always have to "run as admin" to do anything that requires admin privilege.  The user should be used to it, bypassing this requirement could be considered to constitute an elevation of privilege vulnerability.  If it isn't acceptable for non-admin users to have access to the drivers, then it isn't acceptable for non-elevated admin users to have access either.  However, what you could do is create a separate group when your driver is installed, and have that group as well as Administrators in the access rights - that way it is up to the sysadmin how to configure access.

Comment: I am considering creating a separate group during installation, but how to make a member of Administrators group also the member of my group at any moment, in case the user creates an account in Administrators group after my driver installation, my installation script cannot add this new account. Also I tried to add the Administrators group into my new group but failed, it seems that Administrators group is supported to add into other groups?